# pandas : create a datetime index from list and forloop

Tags: python, pandas

If I wrote (and understand) this properly, the following piece of code iterates over a list and create a datetime index with each date value

here is what it looks like:

```
for k in range(len(prediction_times)):
  
            prediction_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=prediction_times[k])
            print(prediction_index)
```

and here is what `prediction_times` look like:

```
['2020-06-15', '2020-06-15', '2020-06-15', '2020-06-15']
```

this yields the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-183-bb5c7db96287> in <module>
      6 predictor.set_prediction_parameters(freq, prediction_length)
      7 
----> 8 list_of_df = predictor.predict(time_series_training[:60])
      9 actual_data = time_series[:5]
     10 

<ipython-input-182-08c8653decf6> in predict(self, ts, cat, encoding, num_samples, quantiles)
     31         req = self.__encode_request(ts, cat, encoding, num_samples, quantiles)
     32         res = super(DeepARPredictor, self).predict(req)
---> 33         return self.__decode_response(res, prediction_times, encoding)
     34 
     35     def __encode_request(self, ts, cat, encoding, num_samples, quantiles):

<ipython-input-182-08c8653decf6> in __decode_response(self, response, prediction_times, encoding)
     48         for k in range(len(prediction_times)):
     49 
---> 50             prediction_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data=prediction_times[k])
     51             #print([prediction_index[k]])
     52 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in __new__(cls, data, freq, tz, normalize, closed, ambiguous, dayfirst, yearfirst, dtype, copy, name)
    235         if is_scalar(data):
    236             raise TypeError(
--> 237                 f"{cls.__name__}() must be called with a "
    238                 f"collection of some kind, {repr(data)} was passed"
    239             )

TypeError: DatetimeIndex() must be called with a collection of some kind, '2020-06-15' was passed
```

to give a bit more context, `prediction_index` will serve as index of the following data:

```
[          0.1         0.9       0.75
0  -98.156296   92.786850  43.232204
1  -78.564545  110.989624  63.177021
2  -73.894463  102.080643  51.134350
3  -84.516640   75.059998  45.414589
4  -65.650047   96.439865  59.942085
[          0.1         0.9       0.75
0  -98.156296   92.786850  43.232204
1  -78.564545  110.989624  63.177021
2  -73.894463  102.080643  51.134350
3  -84.516640   75.059998  45.414589
4  -65.650047   96.439865  59.942085
```

here is the entire forloop:

```
def __decode_response(self, response, prediction_times, encoding):
        
        response_data = json.loads(response.decode(encoding))
        
        list_of_df = []
        
       
        for k in range(len(prediction_times)):
            
            prediction_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data=prediction_times[k])
list_of_df.append(pd.DataFrame(data=response_data['predictions'][k]['quantiles'],index=prediction_index))
        return list_of_df
```

I keep getting the error without finding a way to correct, beside all the others questions  with simular theme. It seems that it is telling me to pass the value as list.

the ultimate result should be a list of dataframes

Comment: I can not reproduce your error message. If I call `pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2020-06-15')`  I get `Must provide freq argument if no data is supplied`. Can you please check if you are sharing the lines of code where the error appears?

Comment: I updated to show you the full traceback

Comment: How is your question related to your problem and the code you shared in the first place? I will down vote your question. FYI: `prediction_index ` != `time_series_training`.

Comment: my appologies, because the error talked about datetimeindex, I assumed that the problematic part was there, on top of that I don't get what could be wrong with time_series_training. In addition, I tried to keep the issue as concise as possible to conform to the rules of this forum

Answer (score 1):

This should work and gives you a DatetimeIndex.

```
date_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data=['2020-06-15', '2020-06-15', '2020-06-15', '2020-06-15'])
```

To return an item of the list, you can iterate over this list:

```
for item in date_index:
    print(item)
```

Comment: this does not work unfortunately, should not the forloop return one index per list value?

Comment: What exactly is the goal you want achieve? My answer creates you a list with 4 Timestamp-objects.

Comment: I updated my question to give more context to the problem at hand